# How to calculate inverse of large matrix?

Tags: matrices, math-software

I have recently been looking at random variables and did come upon the below matrix (in image form because it is too large to copy):

[image]

I have been attempting to find the inverse of this matrix, and have only been able to find decimal approximations. Does anyone know of any software or site that could compute the exact inverse?

Comment: Mathematica and Python will be able to invert it exactly.

Comment: If you use Python, you'll want to use the sympy module to get an exact inverse

Comment: If you only want a numerical result, [this](https://pastebin.com/f9emMC2c) is an example of how.

Comment: I tried to use the sympy modules and numpy modules in python, but both only give decimal approximations. Is there any way to get the exact fractional form?

Comment: I think you have to force python to give you an exact output with sympy. I'm pretty sure there's a command to put output in fraction form.

Comment: If you were to use MathJax rather than a picture, it could be copied and pasted into Mathematica easily, and the determinant computed quickly.